# Node Supervisor exited with code 0

Tags: node.js, node-supervisor

I've just started getting into node.js, running through a few tutorials. I'm just trying out node-supervisor, but am having some trouble getting it running. I'm using express to set up an app, then installing the supervisor package.

Starting the App using:

```
npm start
```

Does exactly as I'd expect, everything works as it has done a few times before.

However if I start supervisor (`node_module\.bin\supervisor app.js`), I get the following message:

```
Starting child process with 'node app.js'
Program node app.js exited with code 0
```

I've looked everywhere I can for an answer but am stumped. I'm probably doing something stupid, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Here is my current package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "~1.3.0",
    "less-middleware": "0.1.15",
    "supervisor": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you starting node supervisor?  Include in your question any commands executed, as well as your `package.json`.

Comment: +1, I'm facing the same issue here. Tried nodemon as well, but it didn't work

Answer (score 9):

Reconfigure your `package.json`. You have to change the `start` command in `scripts` before running `npm start`

**Supervisor**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "supervisor ./bin/www",
}
```

And a similar change for **Nodemon** as well,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately this still results in the same error, exactly as if I was running the command directly in the command line.

Comment: What does the error message say? Does it still say `Starting child process with 'node app.js'`

Comment: It is the same error, except says `node ./bin/www` instead of `node app.js`.

Comment: Can you share the contents of `package.json`?